# how to always handle ctrl c signal after 10 secs

Tags: c, linux, signals, sleep

when ever user press ctrl c , according to my requirement i should handle it only after 10 secs .

For this i added sleep(10) inside signal handler function which actually works .
I am not sure how it works . Is it the right way to implement it .Will sleep break anything if it is called inside a signal handler . I am really wonder how it works .What is the right way to implement this

```
signal_hanlder(int sig num)
{
    sleep(10);
    my_handler();
}
```

Comment: What exactly are your doubts? According to the [signal manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) `sleep` is async safe so is ok to call in a signal handler. But whether that is the best/right way to do it depends on your exact requirements. For example, if the requirement is that the program runs normally for another 10 seconds before the signal is handled then obviously the above code would not meet that requirement as `sleep` suspends execution.

Comment: @kaylum.: i am just worried whether it is right or wrong . I am not sure how a signal handler could sleep . what do you mean by "program runs normally for another 10 seconds before the signal is handled then obviously the above code would not meet that requirement as sleep suspends execution" . suspends the execution of what ?this signal handler or some thread ?

Comment: For SIGINT the signal handler can run in any of the threads within a process. When a signal handler is running the normal thread execution is interrupted and will not resume until the signal handler returns. So if you call `sleep` in the signal handler it means that the normal thread execution is also suspended during the sleep time. Whether that is right behaviour or not depends on your requirements.

Comment: What is the point of a program freezing for 10 seconds? It is much more likely that it should continue to play Tower of Hanoi (or whatever it does) for 10 seconds before exiting.

Comment: when i tried , the thread which i was expecting to run for 10 secs was running as expected . can i set a call back function after 10 secs ?

Comment: According to https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/c/SIG30-C.+Call+only+asynchronous-safe+functions+within+signal+handlers `sleep()` is one of the POSIX async-signal-safe functions, which means you're allowed to call it in a signal handler.

Comment: @barmar: but i want the system to run in the mean time

Answer (score 1):

If you want the thread to continue running, use [`alarm()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/alarm) to schedule a wakeup 10 seconds later.

```
signal(SIGALRM, my_handler);

void signal_handler(int sig_num) {
    alarm(10);
}
```